# Minus-plus symbol disappears inside \raisebox{}{}

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am attempting to raise an `\mp` minus-plus symbol slightly to match an existing typeset equation. The problem is that the `\mp` symbol disappears when I put it inside a `\raisebox{}{}`. It works fine when I use a `\pm` symbol. I only have this one instance so I thought `\raisebox` would be a quick and easy fix. If I put the `\mp` inside an `\fbox` it doesn't look like there is any character inside.

The existing equation is illustrated here:
[image: existing typeset equation]

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  math-style=french
]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Why this $\mp$ disappears?
\[PH = {\raisebox{1pt}{\mp}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\]
But this $\pm$ does not?
\[PH = {\raisebox{1pt}{\pm}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\]
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

produces:
[image: compiled image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A side effect of `unicode-math` is that commands that are traditionally math mode work in text but only if the text font has the character,.

Your log will show

```
Missing character: There is no ∓ (U+2213) in font [lmroman12-regular]:+tlig;!
```

`\raisebox` is like `\mbox` and takes you out of math, so in traditional tex, both commands would have given errors, the fix is the same, go back in to math with `$\mp$` and `$\pm$`.